# return a $post with related user model after update in Laravel

Tags: laravel, post, model

Is there any way to return the $post after update along the user information? Example:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{

    //on_put, from_user, NewDesc
    // define rules
    $rules = array(

        'NewDesc' => 'max:600'

    );

    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

    if ($validator->fails())
    {
        return Response()->json($validator);
    }
    else{

        $post = Post::find($id);

        $description = $request->input('NewDesc');

        $post->update(['description' => $description]);

        return Response()->json($post);

    }

}
```

This returns the new updated $post to my script but what if I want to send also the user data with it?

Comment: **helper functions** should be `lowercase` in Laravel, and Facade accessors should be `UpperCamelCase`. Therefore to stop code smell, you should be using `return response()->json`, not `return Response()->json`

Answer (score 1):

You haven't really given us the information about the users and how they relate, so I will guess...

Try something like...

```
return Response()->json($post->load('user'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that:

```
return Response()->json(['post' => $post, 'userdata' => $userdata]);
```